# How to group object values by key in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I updated my question:

I have 2 objects(from user inputs)

```
a = {id:1, name:'a', age:10, country:''};
b = {id:2, name:'b', age:14, country:'Malaysia'}
```

I will need to always fill the 'a' object into my html table if the object key is match with table td's id; also if 'a' have empty value, 'b' will need to replace it, finally I will need to get the result：

```
result = {id:1, name:'a', age:10, country:'Malaysia'}
```

But I merge 2 object become:

```
[{id:1, name:'a', age:10, country:''},{id:2, name:'b', age:14, country:'Malaysia'}]
```

And I wish to group the values with same key become:

```
[{id:[1,2], name:['a','b'], age:[10,14], country:['Malaysia']}]
```

Now I stuck here, I tried `.map` & `.reduce`, but not success.

I am thinking to fill first value from each array to my html table if the array key is match with my table td's id. And my key is generate from database, so cannot hardcode inside the code.
I will display the key and value in my html table:

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td id='id'>id</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id='name'>name</td>
<td>a</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id='age'>age</td>
<td>10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id='country'>country</td>
<td>Malaysia</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Apologize my english is bad

Comment: What have you tried so far? We can check your code for mistakes.

Comment: i tried .reduce, but need to specific the key in code, i saw other post do like that

Comment: If you are just trying to create the table you don't need to restructure the array for that.

Comment: Original that is 2 objects, but I push them into arr and do the comparison, and i will need to display the 1st value of each key, not sure i am doing the correct way or not

Comment: I am just wondering why you're using this approach. What is your goal? Do you want to fill your HTML with variables that are in your objects?

Comment: ya, will need to fill the object value if the object key is same with the html td's id. Both object value is get from user input, and do the comparison. Because first object might have some empty value and will replace by second object's value

Comment: That would be possible without array merging. For example, use something like ```$('.tr').each()``` (which is basically a loop). You can pass index and element like this: ```$('.tr').each(function(index, element) { // do  your magic here! });``` Then access your object property in array with ```myArray[index].id```, and use something like nullish coalescing operator ```myArray[index].id ?? myArray[index + 1].id```. Provided your elements are in the same order.

Comment: *"Now I stuck here, I tried .map & .reduce, but not success."* Post JavaScript/jQuery that has failed to meet your objective in a [mcve] so that we can fix it for you.

Comment: @Lalalena thanks to the advise, not the correct solution i need but give me the ideas. thanks alot